# Delete Null Values Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I need to write a SQL query that will need to delete all books that are nulled.

So far I have created a query that shows which books are nulled:

Query that shows which books are nulled

[image: Query that shows which books are nulled]

Now I need to figure to figure the SQL query to delete all the books that nulled. I assumed that query would be:

Comment: is book_num  unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
DELETE FROM BOOK
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BOOK B 
  FULL JOIN CHECKOUT C ON C.BOOK_NUM = B.BOOK_NUM 
  WHERE C.CHECK_OUT_DATE IS NULL);
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle Live SQL to run the query you gave me and I'm getting an error that says "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: I am getting an error that says "ORA-00904: "B"."BOOK_NUM": invalid identifier"

Comment: @Jonn, you can try now - there was a typo

Comment: It runs which is good news, but the output says "0 row(s) deleted" instead of 7.

Comment: Now I am getting an error that says "ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SQL_NBCXWVRZWBOOGQVSGSFBHGJLW.SYS_C006433585) violated - child record found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721"

Comment: @Jonn can you please provide your table structure with sample data in question

Comment: I've included an ERD if that helps

Comment: @Jonn, can you provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM BOOK 
 WHERE BOOK_NUM IN
(SELECT B.BOOK_NUM
  FROM BOOK B FULL JOIN CHECKOUT C ON C.BOOK_NUM = B.BOOK_NUM
 WHERE C.CHECK_OUT_DATE IS NULL);
```

The inner query will select all the book_num who do not have a check_out_date.
The outer query will delete the books present in books table if the book_num is returned by the inner query.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21284269)

Comment: Please provide an explanation to how your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what a `FULL JOIN` is doing in a well-defined data model.  Presumably, you want:

```
DELETE FROM BOOK
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CHECKOUT C
                  WHERE C.BOOK_NUM = B.BOOK_NUM AND
                        C.CHECK_OUT_DATE IS NOT NULL
                 );
```